# Continue playing this game until they have 0 or less in the money_amount

Tags: python, currency

I want the user to continue playing this game until they have 0 or less in the money_amount. How can i possibly do this?

```
import numpy as np

random_number = np.random.randint(1, 6)
money_amount = 10

try:
    user_wager = int(input('Your wager: '))
    if (user_wager < 0) or (user_wager > money_amount):
        print("You don't have that amount of money!")
except(ValueError):
    print('Enter a numerical value!')

try:
    user_guess = int(input('Guess: '))
    if (user_guess < 1) or (user_guess > 5):
        print('Please choose a number between 1 and 5!')
    elif user_guess == random_number:
        money_amount += user_wager
        print(f'Correct! You now have ${money_amount}!')
    else:
        money_amount -= user_wager
        print(f'Wrong! The number was {random_number} and you now have ${money_amount}.')
except(ValueError):
    print('Choose a number!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop. From the wiki:

> While loops, like the [ForLoop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), are used for repeating sections of code - but unlike a for loop, the while loop will not run n times, but until a defined condition is no longer met. If the condition is initially false, the loop body will not be executed at all.

For your game you want to loop "while" the player has "more than" "0" dollars. So you're loop will be:

```py
while money_amount > 0:
    # game logic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
while money_amount > 0:
    #game
```

or this way:

```
while 1:
    #game
    if money_amount <= 0:
        break
```

Comment: In the second example, the test should be `money_amount <= 0`

Comment: @Neil yeah sorry, made it by mistake.
This what happen when you "copy paste" the code ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

you can use this logic

```
while True:
    if money_amount > 0:
        break
```

Comment: As written, this will break out of the loop whenever money_amount is positive. The question wants to break out of the loop when money_amount is 0 or less.

Comment: true must be True, Python is case sensitive !